# Maldivian mystery in Sitecore and returning 404 on unsupported languages

Tags: sitecore

A website I am currently working on is currently responding to requests on http://www.mysite.com/dv with 301, where I would have expected a 404.

My site has no content item named DV, there is nothing in the site that corresponds to "DV", and I can't understand why on earth I am seeing this. I originally found these /DV/ URLs while looking at Google Webmaster Tools.

Then I used Fiddler to analyse the request and found

```
Response sent 26 bytes of Cookie data:
    Set-Cookie: wwwwebsite#lang=DV; path=/
```

This appears to correspond to the Maldivian language. I did not enable this language, and it does not appear under /system/Languages.

I then noticed I can also navigate to http://www.mysite.com/de-CH which is not an enabled language on my site either, leading me to believe I will get results like this for every non-enabled language.

Is there a way to return 404 for unsupported languages in Sitecore?

Comment: Have you come across this Stack Overflow question. It may not be applicable, but it's worth looking at just in case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252235/sitecore-uses-302-found-to-redirect-users-to-my-custom-404-page-is-that-legi

Comment: I too want a 404 returned from my page, but the issue I have now is not that it sends a 302 to redirect me to a 404.aspx page, but that it shows the requested page as 200 OK. I while there are some similarities to my question, in my situation I think the solution is to block other languages. I am thinking at the moment that I might need a change to my ItemResolver, but not quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try seeing what your "languageEmbedding" value in the web.config is set to.

It can be set to the following: asNeeded | always | never

I would normally set it to "never" unless you have a site, which is set in multiplate languages, then set it to "always". The default is "asNeeded" which I frankly find kinda silly :)

Comment: Actually I should have specified in the question, but my site does support 2 languages. But not Maldivian / Dhivehi :)

Comment: Does it change anything if you set it to "never" ? you can still switch language with "?sc_lang=en", but links wont have the domain/en/page.aspx

Comment: asNeeded also makes me uncomfortable ... I'll update this page with a solution in the next few days

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having sounds similar to http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?postid=51681 but I an't find `DV` in `LanguageDefinitions.config`. I am also able to replicate your error so I don't think it is environment specific to your implementation. Would suggest you contact Sitecore Support.

Comment: I've talked to Sitecore about this issue now, and will update this question once I've got a working solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is actually related to languages at all. If you were to add any random characters in place of the DV, you'd still get a 302 redirect to a 404. Perhaps without the language cookie though.

You should follow the directions here to turn on server side error page redirects.

http://herskind.co.uk/blog/2012/03/sitecore-404-without-302

Comment: Only entering valid language codes causes this behaviour; for example DV, FO, de-CH