# Sitecore VirtualFolder that is a Language Abreviation

Tags: sitecore

We need to have our site have a starting url of domain.com/fa/en

I can setup the site node to have the virtualFolder and physicalFolder set to "/foo/bar" and things work when I go to domain.com/foo/bar I am shown the home page.

However if I set this to "/fa/en" I get a document not found. I believe what is happening is Sitecore sees the "fa" and thinks it is a language setter (fa is portugese I think). How do I tell Sitecore that this is not a language indicator and it is a virtualFolder?

thanks,
~james

Comment: `fa` is Farsi (Iran) language, and so Sitecore resolves this "successfully". It looks like you've run across the same problem as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139102/maldivian-mystery-in-sitecore-and-returning-404-on-unsupported-languages). Sitecore expects the first 2 chars to be language code (or 5 for ISO code). Is `en` in your example supposed to be English? Is your site multilingual or is this just another prefix?

Comment: Thanks, this worked and got me on the right track to acomodate if anyone else needs it: http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/11/sitecore-item-with-language-name.html and http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PageIndex=1&PostID=61854

Answer (score 0):

The fix is in these two links in case anyone else runs into the issue:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PageIndex=1&PostID=61854
http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/11/sitecore-item-with-language-name.html