# HttpHeader Status Code to 404

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I looked it up various links like these: [Link1](http://www.partechit.nl/en/blog/2012/11/return-404-status-code-when-itemnotfound-page-is-loaded#.UYPBILWG3yU), [Link2](http://herskind.co.uk/blog/2012/03/sitecore-404-without-302), [Link3](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/sitecore-404-without-302/) I am coming to conclusion that, I cannot fix the issue that I am facing. I have an **Error** page item, which is calling a sublayout to show different error messages for different codes. Need to produce a proper 404 status code while providing an error page in Sitecore. Same question asked here: [Sitecore uses "302 found" to redirect users to my custom 404 page - is that legitimate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252235/sitecore-uses-302-found-to-redirect-users-to-my-custom-404-page-is-that-legi)

Please refer attached image to see what I am talking about: [image: Error Page]

Thank you for your inputs!

Answer (score 4):

Did you look at the [Sitecore Error Manager](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Error_Manager.aspx) module which will let you set different pages for different error codes?

Comment: Yes! But we have already implement the Error Sublayout control and dont want to change it.

Comment: So what do you actually want, just a 404 error or all the different possible different types of error codes? What specific codes are you trying to handle in your sublayout? Sometimes it is easier to make the change now rather than trying to re-invent the wheel, unless you have something very specific happening.

Comment: I agree with this, I would definitely look at using the Sitecore Error Manager. I've gone down the path you are and still have not managed to solve this problem properly on my own. Furthermore, you probably don't need to actually change your sublayout as all I did was tell the module where my error page was.

Comment: @jammykam: If you refer to the image, you can see that the first page has 302 Found header on it, however, its not a valid page in the content tree. I want that to be 404.

Comment: @dhulk: I agree! But this site was created by Sitecore consultants, and I (full time software dev) dont have that much time to re-invent the wheel here. Its a bug, not a task!

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not suggesting you re-invent anything (although if your current solution isn't working, I'd say it would be worth it regardless). For reference, it took me about 15 minutes to install this module and use it with my existing error page, nothing was modified in my solution outside of the steps needed to install the module (package installation and a few config updates).

Comment: Difficult to diagnose without more info then, the articles you linked to should fix the issue you are having. What version and build of Sitecore are you using?