# How to add pdf in sitecore settings to get 404 and 301 status

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have customError handler which handles the 404 request and it works fine when page not found it gives 404. but the problem is when pdf is not found it is showing 404 along with 302. i want to show 301 and 404.
is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: I suggest you to read these old posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252235/sitecore-uses-302-found-to-redirect-users-to-my-custom-404-page-is-that-legi and https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/sitecore-404-without-302/. Hopefully, you will find them helpful.

Comment: thanks but its still not resolved :(